# natural numbers multiplication and category theory product

Tags: category-theory

Are the multiplication and summation on natural numbers kind of product and coproduct in category theory? and if yes then how?

Comment: Yes; consider the category of finite sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the categorical product and coproduct correspond to multiplication and addition in a fairly intuitive way.

Suppose we work in the category $\mathcal C$ of finite sets. For each finite set $X$, we of course have a number $|X|$, which is its cardinality. Taking the cardinality corresponds to counting the objects of $X$.

The coproduct $X \sqcup Y$ is simply a disjoint union. We have the relation
$$|X\sqcup Y|=|X|+|Y|.$$
This relation just says that, in order to count a set composed of two smaller sets, we just count each of the smaller sets and add them.

The product $X\times Y$ is the set of pairs $(x,y)$ with $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$. We have the relation
$$|X\times Y|=|X|\cdot |Y|.$$ 
This relation states that, if we wish to count the number of possible combinations of two things, we may count the number of possibilities for each item separately and multiply them.

This connection is fairly nice because the relations more or less express the way that addition and multiplication are related to counting - and I'd imagine that most everyone has encountered these relations implicitly while learning how (and why) to add and multiply.

Comment: Thanks @Milo . That is exactly what I was looking for. And how would we describe the universal property diagrams (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory) ) in terms of what you just said?

Comment: @user650585 It's more fruitful to understand coproducts and products in general and then to see this relation than to start at the universal properties and get here. However, observe that by considering maps from a one element set, I can see that if I pick an element $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$, then there has to be some (unique) way to pair them up as $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ due to the universal property. That is, maps into $X\times Y$ look like pairs of maps to $X$ and $Y$ - so $X\times Y$ better look like pairs of elements of $X$ and $Y$...

Comment: @user650585 ... For the coproduct, observe that a map out of $X\sqcup Y$ is supposed to look like a pair of a map on $X$ and a map on $Y$. In particular, we should have separate bits of $X\sqcup Y$ to specify values on $X$ and $Y$. Thus, $X\sqcup Y$ is supposed to look like $X$ and $Y$ placed together into a single set - which corresponds to the intuition of counting.

Comment: so if we want to follow the diagram of (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory) ) then as you said X1 x X2 can be |X1|.|X2| . Then in that case what could be an example of Y?

Comment: This is a good answer, but I'd like to suggest a minor change : I think it would be better to say that cardinality counts the *elements* of $X$. I think that in this context referring to them as objects can be misleading.